# Whats wrong in this code ? I am trying to change the image of an image button

Tags: android, imagebutton

```
public class AccountSetupActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageButton fbButton;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "FB clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Drawable fbLight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fborange);
        fbButton.setBackgroundDrawable(fbLight);
        // fbButton.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setupaccounts);
        fbButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fbButton);
        fbButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

}
```

Comment: what's wrong with it? what happens?

Comment: logcat would be helpful.

Comment: no errors of anykind. But it doesnt change the background image either. What wrong possibly could i be doing

Comment: Please attach your logcat output ?

Comment: @swayam. there are no errors at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line instead for setting the image:

```
        fbButton.setImageDrawable(fbLight);
```

I think you intend to set the front-most image, but are setting the background image instead

Comment: That does it. Yes the method i was trying was just setting the background image, not the foreground image. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 buttonName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageName);
```

Comment: it throws ResourceNotFoundException

Comment: see the updated answer and try,.,..and comment the line where you are getting drawable object

Comment: have you added the resource?

Comment: There is no error, the logcat doesnt show any. The toast also pops up tat means the control reaches the onClick() method.. But still the image doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

try out this:

`fbButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.fborange)`